# TFS 2015 not picking up groups from the AD

Tags: active-directory, team-foundation-server

I've got a VM with AD & TFS 2015 set up.

I've added a group to the AD : 'g_buildagents' and I was attempting to add that group to the TFS Group containing the build service accounts (BuildServiceAccounts?), however TFS failed to retrieve the 'g_buildagents' group from the AD.

Any idea why?

Comment: Check the `SCOPE` of the AD group. I don't remember without looking but if it's `DOMAIN LOCAL`, change to `GLOBAL` or vice versa... I think it's `GLOBAL` so give that a stab, and then refresh TFS just to be thorough and then see if it'll see the AD group afterwards. Some of this may depend on your domain functional and forest functional levels as well.

Comment: The sync jobs runs every hours: have you waited enough?

Comment: I've installed it 2 days ago, so I'd say - yes.

Comment: Then, it could be a simple UI thing: the first time you use an AD account (user or group) not referenced by any other group, you must refer to it using DOMAIN\account syntax.

Comment: That worked! If you'd kindly copy/paste your comment - I'll accept it as an answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Background info

TFS use a background synchronization job, scheduled every hour, to look for changes in Active Directory (or the local machine workgroup if the server is not domain joined). You can force the job to run using any of [these techniques](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/24305.how-to-synchronize-tfs-users-with-ad-active-directory.aspx).

It could be that you still do not see the user or name listed in the UI even if synchronization is working. The synchronization job does not automatically creates a user profile in the database for every user or group in the database, to avoid useless growth in big enterprises.

#### The solution

In such a case, the first time you use a new AD account (user or group), you must refer to it using `DOMAIN\account` syntax so that TFS look up in AD on the fly and insert a profile record in the database for the account.

#### Further Troubleshooting

Mr. Hinsh has a good [troubleshooting guide](http://nakedalm.com/active-directory-groups-not-syncing-with-team-foundation-server-2010/) if you still have troubles.